# List with int array - accessing the array

Tags: c#, list

I have a class (students) with say 2 strings and an int array

A second class then does this:

```
List<student> myS = new List<student>();
```

All of this works correctly and I have a list containing multiple students. I am however having difficulty accessing the values within the `int[]`.

So, my student list is populated from a database and into a list.

I then have a generic class which has a parameter List which I then want as a data table. The generic class will be called for the student class, subjects class and other classes - some of which may contain arrays and some which do not.

If I debug and step through, I get the following:
(() myS.stu[6].termMark[1] and the value is 50. However if I enter int d =stu[6].termMark[1] the error is T does not contain a definition for termMark and no extension method 'termMark' accepting a first argument of type T could be found.

`int d = myS[0][1]` returns the error

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'T'

. I have tried various things like creating a separate list and adding it to myS. Nothing works.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am fairly new to this and probably missing the obvious...

Comment: int d = myS[0].YourArrayFieldName[1] ;  (The field must be public)

Comment: You have to use the property name to get the values from student object  int d = myS[0].ArrayProperty[1]

Comment: student is not a 2 stage list so what is with the second index

Comment: I guess you have a generic function somewhere.Show us the entire example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read about [Generic Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)
You cannot do much with an argument of type T.
If your function accepts arguments of type student , add a constraint like this

```
private static void NewMethod<T>(List<T> myS) where T : student
{
        int d = myS[0].IntArray[1];
}
```

The following is not related your problem...
If you add an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) to your class you can make it a little shorter

```
public class student
{
    public int[] IntArray;

    public int this[int x]
    {
        get
        {
            return IntArray[x];
        }
    }
}
private static void NewMethod<T>(List<T> myS) where T : student
{
        int d = myS[0][3];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the type `T` does not hold any definition for indexers. But, your field (`int[]`) does. So, instead of calling the indexer upon your object (`student`) call it on the field of it. So, for this answer I would assume that your object is declared as class like this

```
public class student {
   public string S { get; set; }
   public string s { get; set; }
   public int[] integers { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can indeed call the `indexers` on the integers field but not on the student object itself (it does not have any indexing mechanism). Such as,

```
int d = myS[0].integers[1]; // <-- your code should be
```

The above code (if compiled) would give you the element at the index 1 (2nd element) of the first object in the list. You were instead calling the element at index 1 of the student (which does not have indexers?).

Comment: myS[0] is obviously of type T that's why he gets that error.Even if he add an indexer in his class he will still get that error...